# Pop Up varias vistas en Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Me gustaría crear un Pop up y que aparezca con un pequeño delay cuando se cargue la vista de el home (Como los pop up con promociones que salen al inicio de los e-commerce, etc), en angular js no se pueden cargar dos vistas, me gustaría saber si esto se realiza con una directiva y como pordría implementarlo.

[image: Este es el pop up que quiero introducir en mi vista]

Comment: Probaste con las directivas predeterminadas? ng-include te sirve para incluir múltiples vistas en una. O derechamente crear un script que use ng-template. Te dejo un ejemplo de esto último en plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/i36g265azWa2KVq7AHYA?p=info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ponerlo en una directiva o no seria tu decisión pero se vería forzado crear una directiva y hacer esto:

```
<modal-retrazado retrazo="5000" />
```

Lo mejor seria crear un `.factory` y llamar la modal *desde el codigo* y no de la vista:

```js
angular.module("app",[]).factory("modalRetrazado",function($timeout){
      return {
        mostrar:function(retrazo){
         $timeout(function(){


          var modal = '<div class="modal-content">'+
     ' <div class="modal-header">'+
        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>'+
        '<h4 class="modal-title">BUENOS DIAS!</h4>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div class="modal-body">'+
        '<p>ESCRIBE TU ANUNCIO AQUI...</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div class="modal-footer">'+
        '<button type="button" class="close btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+
        
      '</div>'+
    '</div>'+
  '</div>'+
'</div>';

         // Agregamos la modal al DOM
         $("body").append(modal)
         .find(".modal-content .close")
         .click(function(){
           // cerramos al modal al dar click a cerrar
           $(this).closest(".modal-content").remove();
         });
            
         },retrazo || 5000);
       }
      } 
})

.controller("NombreControlador",function($scope, modalRetrazado){
       modalRetrazado.mostrar(5000)// que inicie a los 5 segundos;
      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css"
rel=stylesheet href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="NombreControlador" />
</div>
```